# Client sending message to Server over Websocket does not work

Tags: javascript, websocket, sensors

I have a client, which listens to two sensor variables and is connected to a websocket server. The value of these sensor variables to be send to the websocket server with following implementation:

```
const ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + host + port);
console.log('sent');

ws.onopen = function (event) {
  //listening to sensor values
  monitoredItem1.on("changed",function(dataValue){      
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(" rotation ", dataValue.value.value));
    //console.log('sent');
    console.log(" % rotation = ", (dataValue.value.value).toString());
  });

  //listening to sensor values
  monitoredItem2.on("changed",function(dataValue){
    console.log(" % pressure = ", dataValue.value.value);
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(" pressure ", dataValue.value.value));
    //console.log('sent');
  });
};
```

And the server looks likes this:

```
var Server = require('ws').Server;
var port = process.env.PORT || 8081;
var ws = new Server({port: port});

ws.on("connection", function(w) {
 w.on('message', function(msg){
  console.log('message from client', msg);
 });
});
```

But the output of the server is like this:

```
message from client " rotation "
message from client " pressure "
message from client " pressure "
message from client " pressure "
message from client " pressure "
message from client " pressure "
message from client " rotation "
message from client " rotation "
message from client " pressure "
```

Why is the websocket server not receiving the numbers? Even when I stringify the `dataValue.value.value` it does not work? Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: I do not know what your host and port parameters look like, but the correct format should include a colon between host and port, like "ws://" + host + ":" + port

Comment: She had that setup.

Comment: i dont get what you want you recieve what you sent? there is nothing missing - maybe `JSON.stringify(\`pressure ${data.data.value}\`, null)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are not accessing the JSON object correctly, but I do not know your JSON structure to provide an example with your JSON data.

When using JSON stringily two value's such as `ws.send(JSON.stringify(" rotation ", dataValue.value.value));`. It is only going to stringify the `" rotation "` part in the output.

But let's say that your data is setup like this. This is how you could access it.

```js
const data = {
    pressure: 'value-pressure',
    rotation: 'value-rotation',
    embed: {
        value: 'value-embed'
    }

};

console.log(data.pressure); // value-pressure
console.log(data.rotation); // value-rotation
console.log(data.embed.value) // value-embed
```

You always could convert it to a string using `toString()` before sending, then re-convert it to JSON with `JSON.parse` after receiving it to access JSON.

I made this little example to test using `JSON.stringify()`, it sent it, just didn't know your data format. Send a JSON through a web socket and then access the object.

```
const WebSocket = require('ws')
var Server = require('ws').Server;
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var ws = new Server({port: port});

ws.on("connection", function(w) {
    w.on('message', function(msg){
        let data = JSON.parse(msg);
        console.log('Incoming', data.pressure); // Access data.pressure value
    });
});
```

And to send

```
const WebSocket = require('ws')
const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000");
console.log('sent');

ws.onopen = function (event) {
    let data = {
        pressure: 'value',
        rotation: 'rotation',
    };
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(data)) // Send all the data
};
```

Comment: JSON.stringify takes 3 parameters: `JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]])`

Comment: My bad, didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using {} around the data which will make it a JS object , and also json.stringify() accept only one argument doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) as value to convert , the first argument that's why only the "pressure " is being converted and being sent.

```
 ws.send(JSON.stringify({"pressure": dataValue.value.value}));
```